# Does the javascript ternary operator only accept single values?

Tags: javascript

So here is a typical ternary example:

```
eatApples === true ? "eat apple" : "don't eat apple";
```

I understand this part, but is it possible to also assign values if the condition comes out to be true? Like this:

```
eatApples === true ? greenApples = "Best Apples" : "don't eat apple";
```

Or does ternary operators only hold single values? The reason i'm asking is my current example does not seem to allow me to set a value if the expression is true.

Comment: What value do you expect `greenApples` to have if the condition is false? You say that you understand the ternary operator, but seem unsure if you can assign the result to a variable using the simple `geenApples = eatApples === true ? "Best Apples" : "don't eat apple";`

Comment: "You say that you understand the ternary operator". No I never said that. I said I understand "this part" of the ternary operator. If I understood the entire thing, I would of never needed to ask the question.

Comment: Yes, javascript ternary operator accept only one value but you can pass there multiple conditions read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) in details.

Comment: "this part" seemed to refer to the expression itself, but if you understood that the expression itself is just an expression (more complicated than but similar to something like "hello" + " world") then you would have understood that it can be directly assigned to a variable. I was uncertain if that is what you were trying to do, or if you were only trying to assign something the `greenApples` only in the `true` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break that ternary operator, `eatApples === true ? greenApples = "Best Apples" : "don't eat apple"` :

- `eatApples === true` the condition and we also don't have a variable that we'll assign the ternary's result to.
- `greenApples = "Best Apples"` if the ternary validates to `true` then `"Best Apples"` will be assigned to `greenApples` and nothing else.
- `: "don't eat apple"` if it validates to `false` nothing will happen as we don't have that ternary operator as the right hand side of an assignment thus `"don't eat apple"` is returned and it's not stored in anywhere.

You can assign the ternary operator to `greenApples` like `greenApples = eatApples === true ? "Best Apples" : "don't eat apple"` but that will result in `greenApples` having `"don't eat apple"` as the value if the ternary validates to false.

As I can tell from your code, you only need to assign `"Best Apples"` to `greenApples` if `eatApples === true` and if it's (`eatApples`) value is other than `true` you won't do nothing, if so you can just use the `&&` operator : `eatApples === true && (greenApples = "Best Apples")` and don't forget the parenthesis arround `greenApples = "Best Apples"` otherwise you'll get an error.

```js
eatApples = true;
greenApples = 'just for testing!';
eatApples === true && (greenApples = "Best Apples");
console.log(greenApples); /** Best Apples **/

eatApples = 1; /** not exactly "true" **/
greenApples = 'just for testing!';
eatApples === true && (greenApples = "Best Apples");
console.log(greenApples); /** just for testing! **/
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the ternary operator returns a value, you can directly assign the result of the ternary operator to your variable:

```
greenApples = eatApples === true ? "Best Apples" : "don't eat apple";
```

If you only want to assign something to `greenApples` in the true case (and perhaps do something else when the condition is false), there really is no reason to use the ternary operator. In that case just use the regular `if ... else` statement:

```
if(eatApples === true){
    greenApples = "Best Apples";
} else {
    //something else with "don't eat apple"?
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use this syntax

```
greenApples = eatApples === true ? "Best Apples" : "don't eat apple";
console.log(greenApples);
```

try it if it not work  tell me